# Error handling from a business layer to the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, error-handling

I'm running a static main() and do an app.Run() to startup a WPF window. It's basically a viewmodel first with a bunch of user controls. From there the user clicks a connect button which starts a Task.Run() within another static class.

When my task runs into exceptions they bubble back to the app.Run() and not the connect button.  I guess they're reporting to the calling thread not where the task was started. Some of the errors I can deal with at the task level but others need to be seen by the user.

So my question is what would be a good practice to get these errors to the UI?

My current async....

```
   private static async void MainMountLoopAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_ctsMount == null) _ctsMount = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var ct = _ctsMount.Token;
            var task =  Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    MoveAxes();
                }
            }, ct);
            await task;
            task.Wait(ct);
            AbortSlew();
            MainLoopRunning = false;
            SkySystem.ConnectSerial = false;
            IsSkyConnected = SkySystem.ConnectSerial;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MainLoopRunning = false;
            MonitorLog.LogToMonitor(MonitorDevice.Telescope, MonitorCategory.Server, MonitorType.Information,
                $"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Cancel Main Loop Task Requested");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MainLoopRunning = false;
            MonitorLog.LogToMonitor(MonitorDevice.Telescope, MonitorCategory.Server, MonitorType.Error,
                $"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Message:{ex.Message} Stack:{ex.StackTrace}");
            AlertState = true;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read: [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)? It might be easier to answer if you provided a small code sample.

Comment: Yeah I read that, but My viewmodel called the async process.  All the exceptions are going back to the app.Run() spot and not the viewmodel.  So just need a way to get exceptions back to the viewmodel.  Only way I see it to update a property with an exception and keep checking it in the view model.   Hopefully there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

In short your *Exceptions* are unobserved (that's to say you are starting fire and forget tasks).

Some considerations :

1. If you are using `Task.Run()` then use [Task.ContinueWith](http://Task.ContinueWith%20Method), there are many examples on how to do this. However, the benefit for fire and forget tasks (term used loosely) is that you can check if there has been an exception thrown from the calling method and handle accordingly.
2. Take this one step further and use `async` and `await` where possible. It takes care of continuations and error handling, it frees up the UI and is neater in just about every respect.

**Examples**

```
public void ContinueWithOperation()  
{  
   Task<string> t = Task.Run(() => LongRunningOperation("Continuewith", 500));  
   t.ContinueWith((t1) =>  
   {  
      // check t1 for errors here
      Console.WriteLine(t1.Result);  
   });  
}  


//Fake async! very smelly
public async Task AsyncOperation()  
{
   try
   {
      string t = await Task.Run(() => LongRunningOperation("AsyncOperation", 1000));  
      Console.WriteLine(t);  
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       // check for errors here
   }
} 

// Ideally 
public async Task OperationAsync()  
{
   try
   {
      string t = await LongRunningOperationAsync("AsyncOperation", 1000);  
      Console.WriteLine(t);  
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       // check for errors here
   }
}
```

Comment: I always suggest `await` over `Task.Run` as well. Nice hat btw

Comment: Already doing all this, just need to know a good way to return the exceptions to the UI.  They are going to the main thread not to the UI where I started the async process.  I need to inform the UI of some errors so I was looking for a good way to do it.

Comment: @robmorgan then this is a lesson on being specific as none of this was clear in your question. I suggest you create bindable property, bind to it, then update it

Comment: @robmorgan here is a good place to start https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm and https://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU822AU822&ei=4I4QXK-hDNP5rQGps53wCw&q=data+binding+wpf&oq=data+binding+wpf&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0..62...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.byLCthLCq5U